# If statement that removes everything to the right of the word if the word is repeated in excel

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Please could someone help me in formulating vba code that can remove everything after the last occurrence of a word if that word appears more than once.

My code so far that works to remove - it's the ifs that I struggle with
(for example, when checking the whole column, if Adam appears once, delete everything after Adam in the cell, if Adam appears 3 times, delete everything after the last occurrence of Adam):

For example, adam ate a pear. Adam ate an apple - should result in Adam ate a pear.

However, if it was adam ate a pear - then the result would be a blank cell

I have the code that removes the word but I am struggling on the if statements for the criteria above, if someone could help please.

```
Sub removeData()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim i As Long, lr As Long
Dim arr

' *A being the column in excel*

lr = ws.Range("A"& ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i=1 To lr
    arr = Split(ws.Range("A"&i), "Adam")
    ws.Range("D"&i) = arr(0)
    ar=""

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Lookup `InStr` to locate a string within another string.  Then lookup `Mid` to create a substring based on the results of `InStr`.   You can use those two functions to get your results.

Comment: **1)** I would always start a project with `Option Explicit`. This will help you avoid issues like misspelling your own variables. (I'm assuming `ar=""` should be `arr = ""`. **2)** Check out [How to clear an Array](https://excelchamps.com/vba/arrays/clear-array/) as it might help out. **3)** I'm a little confused about what the data you're working with looks like; is "adam ate a pear. Adam ate an apple" all in one cell? or in many? do you want to apply your logic just to each cell, or do you want the last cell to contain adam cleared?

Answer (score 1):

### Remove After the Last Occurrence of a Substring

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveData()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const WORKSHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "D"
    Const SEARCH_STRING As String = "Adam"
    Const MATCH_CASE As Boolean = False
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WORKSHEET_NAME)
    
    ' Reference the Source (single-column) range.
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = ws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL)
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = ws.Range(sfCell, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, sfCell.Column).End(xlUp))
    
    ' Write the values from the Source range to an array.
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim Data()
    
    If rCount = 1 Then ' one cell
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = srg.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        Data = srg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Determine the compare method.
    Dim CompareMethod As VbCompareMethod
    CompareMethod = IIf(MATCH_CASE, vbBinaryCompare, vbTextCompare)
    
    ' Loop over the values in the array and replace them
    ' with the resulting strings.
    
    Dim r As Long, sPos As Long, sStr As String
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        sStr = CStr(Data(r, 1))
        sPos = InStrRev(sStr, SEARCH_STRING, , CompareMethod)
        If sPos > 0 Then Data(r, 1) = Trim(Left(sStr, sPos - 1))
    Next r
    
    ' Reference the Destination (single-column) range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.EntireRow.Columns(DST_COLUMN)
    
    ' Write the values from the array to the Destination range.
    drg.Value = Data
                
End Sub
```

Comment: I never considered defining my array `(1 to 1, 1 to 1)` to deal with possible single dimension Arrays from Ranges. That's much better than what I have been doing.

Comment: Thanks @VBasic2008 - however, I get an undefined for vBinaryCompare, if you could help please? Thanks

Comment: `vbBinaryCompare` is a replacement for 0, while `vbTextCompare` is for 1. You can declare `Dim CompareMethod As Long`. So something along these lines may help but I doubt it. I have no idea why this error would occur in this line.